# MERN app on AWS EC2 partly breaks after some time. "Server selection timed out after 30000 ms". Works fine on Heroku

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, amazon-ec2, pm2

So I have a MERN app hosted on Heroku that works just fine no problems. I want to learn how to host on AWS EC2 by hosting the same app there.

I have the React app in one directory and the Mongo/Express in another directory. I build the react app and copy the build directory into the Mongo/Express directory. I then serve the front-end with the command

```
app.use(express.static('build'));
```

This works fine in Heroku. It has been deployed there for over a year now with no problems.

Now when I try to do the hosting in my ubuntu image in AWS EC2 with pm2 it works fine but when I revisit the site after some time (ranging from 10 hours to sometimes 5 days), it loads the frontend just fine but is missing all the entries that should have been fetched from MongoDB.

Looking at the pm2 logs shows this error "Server selection timed out after 30000 ms".

What am I missing; what steps do I need to take in order to ensure the DB connection doesn't time out in this scenario?

Comment: Are you serving using nginx ?

Comment: no. I don't think I know what that is. Just 'pm2 start app.js' an express.js app with pm2.

Comment: How do you serve the app to the web ? Is it through Nginx ?

Comment: no, it is in an AWS ubuntu container being served with pm2